Deprecated 17.0 IOS how to fix for 17.4
Hi onchange with one argument is deprecated need to fix for ios 17.4
.onChange(of: phase) { newValue in
            if timerModel.isStarted {
                if newValue == .background {
                    lastActiveTimeStamp = Date()
                }
                
                if newValue == .active {
                    //Finding the difference
                    let currentTimeStampDiff = Date().timeIntervalSince(lastActiveTimeStamp)
                    if timerModel.totalSeconds - Int(currentTimeStampDiff) <= 0 {
                        timerModel.isStarted = false
                        timerModel.totalSeconds = 0
                        timerModel.isFinished = true
                    } else {
                        timerModel.totalSeconds -= Int(currentTimeStampDiff)
                    }
                }
            }
                
            
        }

I am trying to get my timer to keep working even after i leave the app and when i come back should change based on how long i left for or keep counting down till end and notify me which is implemented. Thank your text you so much for the help in advance

.onChange(of: phase) { _, newValue in
